# Копирование на Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Есть файловый сервер, на 2008R2 и есть клиентский комп на Windows 7, клиентский комп запускает копирование на файловом серваке из одной папки в другую на том же серваке, скорость копирования ограничивается каналом на клиентской машине.

Как сделать так, чтобы трафик не прокачивался через клиента, и копирование шло средствами самого сервера?

Comment: дык через rdp.

Comment: человеку надо интерфейс для многих виндопользователей, которые работали бы с общей папкой, как с любой другой сетевой, но чтобы операции, которые могли бы проходить на сервере локально проходили бы локально, а не через клиентский комп.

Comment: дык через rdp. Иначе никак)

Comment: Спасибо, но, нет, такой вариант увы не подходит.

Comment: можно вебморду прикрутить.